# Can I wait for a child window to load the second page?

Tags: javascript, events, onload, dom-events

There are three accessible pages, `http://localhost/parent.html`, `http://localhost/child1.html` and `http://localhost/child2.php`.
Only `parent.html` is editable for me, whereas the others are not.
`child2.php` is accessible only through a POST request from `child1.html`.

What I want to do is to automate extracting data from every child page.
I'm on `parent.html` now and will access the other two pages from here using a child window.
However, the code which waits for loading the second page doesn't work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>parent.html</title>
    <script>
    function waitForLoading(targetWindow) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        targetWindow.addEventListener("load", resolve);
      });
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () => {
      const childWindow = open("child1.html", "_blank");
      await waitForLoading(childWindow);
      // do something with DOM

      childWindow.document.querySelector("form[action='child2.php']").submit();
      await waitForLoading(childWindow); // getting stuck here
      // do something with DOM           // so, this line is unreachable
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>parent.html</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

My questions are:

1. Why does the code get stuck?
2. How do I wait for a child window to load the second page?
3. If it is impossible, do you know any workarounds to achieve the goal?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Why does the code get stuck?

Even if a child window loads another page, it seems not to run `load` or `DOMContentLoaded` for the second time or later.

## How do I wait for a child window to load the second page?

Loop and watch the loading state of the page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>parent.html</title>
    <script>
    function waitFirstPage(targetWindow) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        targetWindow.addEventListener("load", resolve);
      });
    }
    function movePage(targetWindow, action) {
      const originalDocument = targetWindow.document;
      action();
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        (function loop() {
          if (targetWindow.document !== null
            && targetWindow.document !== originalDocument
            && targetWindow.document.readyState === "complete") {
            resolve();
          }
          setTimeout(loop, 100);
        })();
      });
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () => {
      const childWindow = open("child1.html", "_blank");
      await waitFirstPage(childWindow);
      // do something with DOM

      await movePage(childWindow, () => {
        childWindow.document.querySelector("form[action='child2.html']").submit();
      });
      // do something with DOM
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>parent.html</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

## If it is impossible, do you know any workarounds to achieve the goal?

No need for workarounds since it is possible.